# Need to trigger a space keydown event when on button click using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I need to trigger a space `keydown` event inside a text box when a button is clicked so that a space is achieved inside the text box using jquery

My code which i have Tried

```
var idz, valz;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).delegate('#getRuleStr', 'click', function () {
        $('#' + idz).val($('#preTag').text());
        var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
        e.which = 32;
        $('#' + idz).trigger(e);
    });
    $(document).delegate('.rulez', 'click', function () {
        idz = this.id;
        valz = $('#' + idz).val();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the space in text box then you can achieve this by

```
$('#' + idz).val( $('#' + idz).val()+" ");
```

But If you don't want to use this approach then post your complete code with html.

Comment: I need to achieve the space by the key events when the button click is done because in angular 2 the required error message will not show if a key event is triggered

Answer (score 0):

If you need to insert a character programatically into input element taking into account a caret position you can do this

```
$('.rulez').on('click', function () {
  var caret = document.getElementById(idz).selectionStart;
  var txtVal = jQuery('#' + idz).val();
  var characterToAdd = " ";
  jQuery('#' + idz).val(txtVal.substring(0, caret) + characterToAdd + txtVal.substring(caret) );
});
```

Note that line in your code

```
$('#' + idz).val($('#preTag').text());
```

will rewrite value in $('#' + idz) element and set caret position to end so there is no need to take caret position into account and thus there is no need to calc anything so you can just append space char to input element value.

Comment: I don't want to append the space with out a space-bar click event because am using the angular 2 where I have created the required field validations even after the value is assigned to the textbox from pretag still am getting the required error if I press a key the error goes, so only I need to generate the space key events on click of a button

Comment: Then try using jquery plugin [link](http://bililite.com/inc/jquery.sendkeys.js) sendkeys.

In this case all you need to do is $('#' + idz).sendkeys(' ');